# Apple Script to parse name and create files

Tags: file, applescript, osx-yosemite, create-directory

I am a physician trying to parse files created from Filemaker Pro in the following format:  CCDOC|FamID|PtID|DocType|Date|FileExtension
Where

- CCDOC is prefix identifying clinical care documents
- FamID is Family ID
- PtID is Patient ID
- Type of Document (Radiology, Lab, Consult, etc)
- Date (in format mm_dd_yyy)
- Extension (mostly PDF, but some JPG, etc)

I want to make an Apple Script that will create nested folders based on these types (Family folder contains patient folders in that family, which contain different document types, etc).  Then the files would be moved to that folder.

Can you help me with this?

Here's an image of the file format

[image]

Here's the CSV file which creates them

[image]

Comment: So is it correct to say that only the `FamilyID` and `PatientID` are of significance to this particular script and the rest can be ignored? And further, that you will only end up with say a few hundred folders at the top-level (1 per family) and 1-5(approx) folders in each of those? Nothing else?

Comment: No, Each person will have a folder for each document type, organized by the date of the documents.  So you could, for example, look at your lab or radiology results over time.  There are maybe 7-10 document types.  Then each patient will be grouped in the folder of the family (so a parent, for example, can look at labs of the kids).  I just want to solve the parsing of the names to create folders.  I will deal with permissions and access at a later time.

Comment: Still not very clear... "*each person will have a folder for each document type*" so do you have a list of all possible document types? Or does the script have to read the whole list through once first to work out all the possible types? An example would be useful... can you give 2-3 input records and the corresponding list of folders that would be created?

Comment: Also, if you name folders in the crazy American fashion (mm-dd-yyyy) where the numbers are neither in increasing nor decreasing order of significance) they will never come out in a sensible order ;-)

Comment: Ok, imagine I am reading your CSV. I get the first line and I have the `family` and `patient`, and it's a `Radiology`, now what do I do? Create just Radiology, or do I have to create Radiology, Lab Tests, Finanacial, Images as well? And what do I do with the date? An example would be really useful !!!!

Comment: Create radiology folder (if it doesn't already exist) for those with "Radiology" in the 3rd part of the string and put the documents in there in reverse chronological order.  The same for those with "Lab" in the 3rd part.

Comment: So here we have CCDOC|DOE1234|JOHN2345|RADIOLOGY|03_14_2013.PDF  to go into the radiology folder in chronological order for John in the Doe family.  I may have to add one last area of identifier, as I can imagine like to parse different x-rays or differentiate a colonoscopy from an echocardiogram (both procedures).

Comment: I also will have to find a way to distinguish duplicates, from tests done on the same day, I just realized.  Still, I just want to know how to do this basically, and I'll work out the details from here.  I've already used Hazel on my mac to determine and create the folders based on the |Lab| or |Radiology|, so I think I can parse beyond that using Hazel if I wanted.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I still don't get it... `what` do I have to put in the folder in your example? Is there a file somewhere else to store there? What do I do with the word `PDF`, or `JPG`? What do you mean by *"put the documents in there in reverse chronological order"*? There is no order to a directory - the order is determined by the user in the `Finder` when he clicks on the `Name` or the `Date` or the `Type` at the top of the columns. It really would be easier if you clicked `edit` under your question and added a 2-3 line sample CSV and the resulting hierarchy...

Comment: I also don't care if it's an apple script.  I just need it to automatically look at any files placed in a certain folder ("Patient Care" and sort them based on the family|person|document Type|date.  Shell is fine by me.  I am just a dumb doc trying to wade into this stuff to make care better.  My ultimate goal is to share ALL of my records with my patients.

Comment: I put the requested images at the end of my question (but me being a person of no repute) I couldn't put them as images, so I used links (in my dropbox public folder).

Comment: However, you have still not said what we are supposed to actually *do* with the document name? Do we have to copy it from some unknown place to the folder we create? Do we have to create an empty file with the same name? Also, the document name you specify (with `|` symbol in it) is not very Mac-friendly - is it correct?

Comment: Yes!  The document name will determine where it's put! That's the point.  I want it to be easy to find the documents on my patients (and for my patients to be able to browse their records).  I don't mind doing a different symbol than "|".  I am generating the name of the document, so can use any type of delineator.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention copying any documents from anywhere, nor where I am able to copy them from, nor does your example output tree hierarchy show any documents... come on ;-)

Comment: One final thing: it is the creation of the file itself and putting it into the "Patient Care" folder that would be the trigger for creating folders necessary to index the document.  CSV files are not involved.

Comment: Sounds like we need to create a `Folder Action` that fires the script when documents arrive.

Comment: So there's no CSV involved at all now, correct? Will there be a folder in `Patient Care` called `Landing Zone` where you drop files wrh names containing pipe synbols (|) and they must be distributed into directories contained within their names after these have been created by the script?

Comment: No, I just want the script to trigger when files are placed in the "Patient Care" folder.  This will use/create subdirectories based on the name of the file.

Comment: Mmmm... this seems to have wandered a long way from the original question and as there is no CSV parsing involved any more my `awk` based answer is not appropriate - the solution is probably going to be based on an OSX *Folder Action* plus `mkdir -p`. I would suggest researching that and then maybe asking another question if necessary - hey, questions are free :-) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**

Based on what I have gathered so far, this is about as far as I can get you at the moment. It is pretty well commented so you can see what it is doing. Add an example and I can probably get you further along...

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Go to the Desktop, or wherever the CSV file is and the output tree must be made
cd ~/Desktop || exit

# Parse "data.csv" using "|" as field separator
awk -F'|' '
  {
     # Pick up all fields of record into appropriately named variables
     CCDOC=$1; FamID=$2; PtID=$3; DocType=$4; Date=$5; Ext=$6;

     # Output name of directory to create, surrounded by "" to permit spaces, e.g. "Lab Test"
     print "\"ROOT/" FamID "/" PtID "/" DocType "/" Date "\""

   }' data.csv | xargs mkdir -p
```

Given a `data.csv` file like this:

```
CCDOC|F999|P5678|Consult|02-03-2013|PDF
CCDOC|F7777|P1111|Radiology|03-04-1999|JPG
CCDOC|F999|P4321|Lab Test|06-12-1997|PDF
```

you will get this:

[image]

**Original Answer**

At its heart, the answer to your question is to use the `mkdir -p` command in the shell that makes a directory, INCLUDING ANY NECESSARY INTERVENING DIRECTORIES, without complaining if anything already exists, or doesn't exist, along the way. Try it for yourself by pasting this into the Terminal

```
mkdir -p ~/Desktop/Freddy/Frog/on/a/log
```

and you will get this on your Desktop

[image]

Now, the question is whether to go parsing that Filemaker Pro CSV file using Applescript or not. Personally, I find Applescript so unbelievably verbose as to be unintelligible, and would go with straight `bash` every day of the week... and don't forget you can harness all that `bash` power from Applescript simply by using

```
do shell script xyz
```

Just to give a little example, say you saved the following as a sample file on your Desktop and called it `data.csv`. Note there are two patients (`P5678` and `P4321`) in family `F999`.

```
CCDOC|F999|P5678|Consult|02-03-2013|PDF
CCDOC|F7777|P1111|Radiology|03-04-1999|JPG
CCDOC|F999|P4321|Lab|06-12-1997|PDF
```

You could then paste the following one-liner into your Terminal

```
cd ~/Desktop &&  awk -F'|' '{print "ROOT/" $2 "/" $3}' data.csv | xargs mkdir -p
```

and you would end up with the following already done

[image]

Let me explain how the script works. First it changes directory to your Desktop (`cd ~/Desktop`), and then, provided that worked (`&&`), it starts `awk` and tells it your fields on each line are separated by the vertical bar (`awk -F'|'`). awk will then read all the lines from `data.csv`, and split the fields and number them for you - so `$1` will contain the `CCDOC`, `$2` will contain the `FamilyId`, `$3` will contain the `PatientId`. So for each line in the CSV file, we print `ROOT/FamilyId/PatientId`. In effect, the output of the `awk` script is as follows:

```
ROOT/F999/P5678
ROOT/F7777/P1111
ROOT/F999/P4321
```

However, we pass those lines into `xargs` and tell it to run `mkdir -p` on each one of them, so it effecively does this, which makes the folders I screen-grabbed above.

```
mkdir -p ROOT/F999/P5678
mkdir -p ROOT/F7777/P1111
mkdir -p ROOT/F999/P4321
```

If, rather than doing that from the Terminal, you wanted to do it from Applescript, you would simply put the same commands in a file and call it, say `MarksThing`

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Desktop &&  awk -F'|' '{print "ROOT/" $2 "/" $3}' data.csv | xargs mkdir -p
```

then in Applescript, you would do

```
do shell script "MarksThing"
```

Though you would have to make it executable first with

```
chmod +x MarksThing
```

I know this doesn't completely answer your question but I still don't understand the rest of it. Rather than guess and waste a load of time, you can maybe answer my question (in the `comments` below your original question) and let me know if you are interested in pursuing this *"non-Applescript"* approach before I do too much more.

Comment: Got it so far (I'm pretty sure I do, at least).

Answer (score 0):

Just put in a path for the rootFolder which is where you want the folders to be located. Good luck.

```
set rootFolder to path to desktop

set tempVar to display dialog "Enter the following information separated by \"/\"" & return & "CCDOC/FamID/PtID/DocType/Date/FileExtension" default answer ""
set folderPath to text returned of tempVar

set thePath to POSIX path of rootFolder & folderPath
do shell script "mkdir -p " & quoted form of thePath
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at FileMaker’s AppleScript dictionary and attempt to write an AppleScript that tells FileMaker and Finder to create the files and folders you want, rather than exporting a CSV from FileMaker and then parsing it and creating files from that. You would likely create a much simpler script that is easier to write and to maintain.

If you don’t have access to FileMaker, you might want to write an AppleScript that tells Numbers and Finder to create the files and folders. Numbers can read the CSV for you and Finder can create the folders and move the files. The commands for doing so are in the Numbers AppleScript Dictionary and the Finder AppleScript dictionary and they are fairly easy to learn.

For example, to make your root folder on your Desktop with Finder:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theDesktopFolder to the path to the desktop folder as alias
    set theRootFolderName to "Patient Care"
    set theRootFolder to make new folder at theDesktopFolder with properties {name:theRootFolderName}
end tell
```

… then you can tell Numbers to open the CSV and loop through it column-by-column, cell-by-cell, getting the cell values, and tell Finder to create corresponding folders within theRootFolder object, which is stored as a variable by the above script so that all you have to say is:

```
make new folder at theRootFolder with properties {name:theCellValue}
```

The above script is written in a deliberately verbose way that makes it easier to read and understand. When your script is done, you may share it within another person who may have to, for example, change the “Patient Care” name to “Client Care” or similar and that is easy for them to do in an explicitly-written AppleScript, even if they have no AppleScript skills. That is a major feature of AppleScript.

You can find out how to do repeat loops in AppleScript in the [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). It will also show you how to open the AppleScript Dictionaries for the apps you want to employ, such as Numbers and Finder.

Also note that shell scripting can be dangerous. You can wipe out data in ways that are not possible with AppleScript. If you screw up with AppleScript, you get an error. If you screw up with bash, you can wipe out gigabytes of data. A lot of people on Stack Overflow will answer your AppleScript question with a bash answer, but that is not necessarily a good answer if you don’t have bash experience. Compared to bash, AppleScript has rubber bumpers so that non-programmers can safely create their own solutions.